# Visual studio 2022 .net 6 is not supporting reportviewer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reportviewer, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022 I can't get any report viewer, and I am using .NET6 framework.
Is there any way to still somehow use it?

Comment: Do you mean Reporting Services Projects? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio2022